# How can you prevent a Kindle Fire from auto-mounting on a Mac when you plug it in to USB?

Tags: charging, amazon-kindle-fire

I've got a Kindle Fire and I like to plug it in to my Mac to charge up (and also to do some development.)  It works fine but it is annoying to have to unmount it every time.

Is there any way to prevent it from auto-mounting when you plug it into USB?

Comment: I don't know if this is related to your issue but [check this out](http://www.technipages.com/droid-automatically-mounts-when-plugged-into-pc.html). Basically you could have another app on the system that is enabling that option for you...?

Answer (score 1):

Check Your Phone it should show some setting named 'Connect to PC'. Change the "Default connection type" to "Charge only".

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out.

This works with my 1st gen Kindle Fire and my Mac running OS X.

First, notice that the Kindle Fire mounts as the volume "KINDLE".

Second, realize that there is a file on your OS X installation called /etc/private/fstab which controls filesystem mounting.

Third, use the command `sudo vifs` in Terminal or otherwise edit the /etc/private/fstab file and insert the following lines:

```
# Kindle Fire
LABEL=KINDLE    none    msdos   rw,noauto
```

Fourth, try plugging in your Kindle Fire via USB.  It should not auto-mount anymore.

Bonus: this works for any Android device that auto-mounts when you plug it in.  My new HTC One (Verizon 32GB) auto-mounts HTC Sync Manager.  It uses the label "CDROM".  I added a similar line above, but substituting "CDROM" for "KINDLE" and now it stops prompting me to install HTC Sync Manager.  In this case, I inserted these lines into /etc/private/fstab

```
# HTC One
LABEL=CDROM     none    hfs     rw,noauto
```

Answer (score -1):

There are some USB Cabes that don't support enough power to change data, so they just charge and don't mount. But I don't know how you could find them. Try google for it.